# Access 2007 - Display PDF content on a form

Tags: ms-access

On Access 2007, is there a way to display the content of a PDF, even if it is just the first page, on a form? This PDF saved in a table as attachment.

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: This answer will only work for PDF files stored outside of your database as separate file. They can be located over a network connection, but I do not know how to access them directly from your database table. This [site gives a thorough guide to using the attachments](http://www.cimaware.com/resources/article_135.html), but doesn't show how to actually display them automatically. It is likely functionality not provided by Access.

You can display anything Internet Explorer can display with a `Microsoft Web Browser` Control.

Once you've added the control, you can navigate to whatever you want to display during the load or open event of the form.

For example, if the control is called `WebBrowser0` then the following would work:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.WebBrowser0.Navigate2 "C:\example.pdf" 'Substitute the actual address here.
End Sub
```

This is an extremely versatile method for displaying other content within Access. You can find more information [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I've added a disclaimer and some additional information that is related but still does not solve the exact issue. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The only two methods I know of for previewing a PDF (WebBrowswer as suggested by Daniel and the Adobe Active X control) require a file path to be passed to the control.

I recommend extracting the file from the attachment field and saving it to a temporary location such as `C:\Documents and Settings\username\AppData`. This can be found by using the vba `Environ` command.

Extracting the file is done with the `SaveToFile` method in the embedded DAO recordset (which is how attachments are stored in memory).

#### Example Code

*Assume each record has a field called* `AttachedFile` *and each record has only one attached PDF. The form is using a WebBrowser control named* `PreviewBrowser` *to view the PDF*

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
On Error GoTo ExitSub
    Dim FormRS As DAO.Recordset
    Set FormRS = Me.Recordset

    Dim RecAtt As DAO.Recordset

    If (Me.AttachedFile.AttachmentCount > 0) Then
        Set RecAtt = FormRS.Fields("AttachedFile").Value
        RecAtt.OpenRecordset

        Dim Path As String
        FilePath = Environ("APPDATA") & "\Preview.pdf"

        If (Dir(FilePath) <> "") Then Kill FilePath
        RecAtt.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile FilePath
        Me.PreviewBrowser.Navigate2 FilePath
    End If

ExitSub:
    RecAtt.Close
End Sub
```

Of course the code needs to be a bit more complicated if there are multiple attachments to a given record, but that would be done by manipulating the `RecAtt` recordset.